# Python operator overloading : commutative or right only?

Tags: python, numpy

How is the operator overloading parsed? 
I have a class object `o` and want to do `-1 * o` with the overloaded `__mul__` operator.
Would that be parsed correctly when the left operand is a `-1`? Multiplication should be commutative (except for matrices and cross-products)... ?

Comment: FYI: Multiplication is overloaded by defining `__mul__`, not `__mult__`.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), which describes separate methods for customizing left- and right-hand operations?

Comment: Not all multiplication is commutative. Matrix multiplication, for instance. That's why there's separate left and right multiplication operators.

Comment: Yes matrix or vector vector mult is not. I was looking at scalar - vector products in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what `__rmul__` is for. In your scenario, Python calls `int.__mul__(-1, o)`. `int` doesn't know how to do this operation, so this call returns `NotImplemented`. Python therefore calls `type(o).__rmul__(o, -1)` giving your class the chance to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

Operators are always parsed the same way regardless of overloading.  Because [unary `-` has higher precedence than `*`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `-1 * o` will always be parsed as `(-1) * o`.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is getting at, although his use of "parsing" may misleadingly suggest it.